# How is it possible to typecast a refection Field into another object?

Tags: java, reflection, casting, field

I'm currently using reflection to get the declared Fields of a GUI class. However I cannot find a way to be able to typecast the fields into the object that I need.

What I need is to be able to get the actual object of the Field, so if for example the field returned is of type JLabel, I need to be able to typecast the field in JLabel to have access to the object

The following is the code I'm using, however the actual object component is not being retrieved:

```
for (int i = 0; i< fields.length; i++) {
                this.fields.add(fields[i]);
                Class<?> fieldType = fields[i].getType();
                try {
                    Component c = (Component) fieldType.newInstance();
                    System.out.println(c.getX + " " + c.getY());

                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HeatMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HeatMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

        }
```

Comment: what Exception? please show the stack trace

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? (What do you expect typecasting to do for you?)

Comment: I need to be able to typecast the field into some other UI component as I need to be able to use the UI object... eg converting field to a JLabel

Comment: @ict1991: Please show us the complete stack trace, and more of the code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like this, don't you?

```
(SomeSubClass)fieldType.newInstance();
```

I further assume `fieldType` is a super class of `SomeSubClass`, thus you'd get an exception (most probably a `ClassCastException`).

Example:

```
class A {}
class B extends A{}

fieldType = A.class;

//this would throw an exception since A it NOT a B!
(B)fieldType.newInstance();
```

**Edit**:

To cast the object to something you need use the `instanceof` keyword.

Example:

```
Object value = field.get(objectTheFieldBelongsTo);

if( value instanceof JLabel) {
  JLabel labelValue = (JLabel)value;
  //whatever you want
}
```

Comment: @amit What exception will be thrown? At least the OP told us what is _not_ thrown: `no IllegalAccessException was thrown`:)

Comment: @amit yes that's easy to miss and maybe it's even not correct there. At least it doesn't make sense to tell what is _not_ thrown, otherwise I could add: `no NumberFormatException was thrown` etc. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking doesn't make much sense to me.  And I suspect this is because you don't have a clear conception of what a `Field` object really is.

A `Field` object is a descriptor for a specific field of a class.  It does not represent a field of a specific instance, so "casting it" to the value in a field doesn't make a lot of sense.  In fact, this ...

```
    Class<?> fieldType = f.getType();
    fieldType.newInstance();
```

... is *actually* creating a new instance of the type of the field `f`.  This will bear no relation whatsoever with the value of the `f` field in some existing object.

You *can* get the value of a field in some object, but to do that you need to say which particular object you want the type of:

```
// Assume Foo has a field bar of type Bar

Foo foo = ...
Field<?> f = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("bar");
Bar foobar = (Bar) f.getObject(foo);

Field f = ...
```